# After Saving Calendar Event Error Is Logged To Console

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

The following log gets sent to console just after saving a new Calendar Event.

> 2017-08-27 09:07:42.853594-0400 Class Organizer Pro[1692:293239]
>   eventEditViewController(): Calendar saved 2017-08-27
>   09:07:42.929867-0400 Class Organizer Pro[1692:293642] XPC: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.coreduetd.knowledge was invalidated."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.coreduetd.knowledge was invalidated.} 2017-08-27
>   09:07:42.941417-0400 Class Organizer Pro[1692:293808] error retrieving
>   siri triggers from CoreDuet stream : Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.coreduetd.knowledge was invalidated."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.coreduetd.knowledge was invalidated.} 2017-08-27
>   09:07:43.676386-0400 Class Organizer Pro[1692:293239]
>   eventEditViewController() dismissed

```
@IBAction func setReminder() {
    NSLog("setReminder()")
    if (isAccessToEventStoreGranted) {
        if (self.reminderAlreadyCreated == false) {
            let myEventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

            controller.eventStore = myEventStore
            controller.editViewDelegate = self

            // customize reminder/event
            let earl : URL = URL.init(string: "https://" + StatusReportSettings.branchIOURI(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier) + "/")!
            controller.event?.url = earl
            controller.event?.title = self.statusReportTitle.text!
            controller.event?.notes = self.answerTextField.text!


            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
                NSLog("setReminder() happened")
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        let alertView : UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Access Restricted", message: "This app doesn't have access to your reminders.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertView.show(self, sender: self)
    }
}

func checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus() {
    let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)

    switch (status) {
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        // This happens on first-run
        requestAccessToCalendar()
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        self.isAccessToEventStoreGranted = true
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted, EKAuthorizationStatus.denied:
        self.isAccessToEventStoreGranted = false
        requestAccessToCalendar()
    }
}

func requestAccessToCalendar() {
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {
        (accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in

        if accessGranted == true {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                NSLog("requestAccessToCalendar() Access granted")
                self.isAccessToEventStoreGranted = true
            })
        } else {
            NSLog("requestAccessToCalendar() Access to store not granted")
            self.isAccessToEventStoreGranted = false
        } // end else
    })
} // end requestAccessToCalendar

//    Finishing an Edit
//
//    func eventEditViewController(EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith: EKEventEditViewAction)
//    Required. Invoked with the user is finished editing the event.
//    Getting the Default Calendar
//
//    func eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendar(forNewEvents: EKEventEditViewController)
//    Returns the calendar to use as the default calendar for new events.
//    Constants
//
//    EKEventEditViewAction
//    Describes the action the user took to end editing.

func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
    NSLog("eventEditViewController()")
    switch (action) {
    case EKEventEditViewAction.saved:
        NSLog("eventEditViewController(): Calendar saved")
        self.reminderAlreadyCreated = true
    case EKEventEditViewAction.cancelled:
        NSLog("eventEditViewController(): Calendar cancelled")
        self.reminderAlreadyCreated = false
    case EKEventEditViewAction.deleted:
        NSLog("eventEditViewController(): Calendar deleted")
        self.reminderAlreadyCreated = false
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        NSLog("eventEditViewController() dismissed")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have requested this:

```
 let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)
```

But you need this:

```
 let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.reminder)
```

Reminders are a different type of entity than events.